# rails filter each method on results page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have this filter on the results page of my application

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top: 10px">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="color: #fff; background-color: #1292fd; font-weight:bold">Search Filters</div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="color: #1292fd; font-weight:bold">
      <label for="datefrom">Date From:</label>
      <input type="date" id="datefrom" class="form-control" name="date" value="dd/mm/yyyy">
      <label for="dateto">Date To:</label>
      <input type="date" id="dateto" class="form-control" name="date" value="dd/mm/yyyy">
      <hr>
      <div style="float:right">
        <button class="btn btn-info" name="button">Apply Filters</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Just a simple date from to filter.

What i'm wanting to do is have the results in the each method which is above it filtered between the two dates selected. i'm under the impression i would need something like this:

```
Comment.where(:created_at => @selected_date.beginning_of_day..@selected_date.end_of_day)
```

My controller looks like this at the moment:

```
  def search
    @events = Event.page(params[:page]).per(10).search(params[:search], misspellings: { distance: 1 }, order: { date: :asc, eventname: :asc }, match: :word_start, page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
    if @events.results.any?
      render 'events/results'
    else
      render 'events/noresults'
    end
  end
```

So at the moment im unaware how to get the results to filter with the filter option.

any help is appreciated

Sam

Comment: I am not sure that I got your question, maybe you need to use `model scopes` . Can you edit and explain your question a little more.

Comment: Edited it a little bit